# Unable to get Ubuntu to work full screen in Vmware Player

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

I was trying to install Ubuntu via VMware player but I am unable to get it to full screen. No matter what I do, Ubuntu only takes up like 1/4th of the screen and the rest is Black.

Comment: If you are talking about the X server, which I believe you may be, what is `arandr` or `xrandr` tools reporting for your viewport and other information?  When you say "1/4th of the screen" that is descriptive, but not really helpful, as it says nothing as to what available space there is and if it is something common that may be easily identified by people more familiar with displays and virtual machines.

Comment: You need to increase the size of the screen that Ubuntu thinks it's displaying on - and VMware player will then use the black borders (it does this with my "Backtrack 5 r3" VM as well)

Comment: dav1dsm1th can you tell me the steps of how to achieve this?

Comment: How an I achieve that dav1dsm1th?

Answer (score 0):

I know its pretty late.....might be helpful for others who have just faced this.

First you will have to change the display settings where you can select the resolution 
to be the same as the Host OS.

After this, VMWare will be displaying horizontal and vertical scroll bars which will interfere with the guest OS.

For this :

Right click on the guest OS -> Settings -> Click on Options Tab -> Unity -> Uncheck Show borders and Show badges.

Now start the guest OS , change display resolution to same as Host OS